# Show that : $B_1(0,L^\infty((\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})))$ is compact in the weak topology $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and  $B_1(0,L^\infty((\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})))$, the closed unit ball of $L^\infty((\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}))$.

Show that : $B_1(0,L^\infty((\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})))$  is compact in the weak topology $\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)$.

> Hint :

We say that :
$B_1(0,L^\infty((\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})))$  is compact in the weak topology $\sigma(L^\infty,L^1)$.
Show that :

$$
 \begin{array}{lll}
i: & (L^\infty ,\sigma(L^\infty,L^1))&\longrightarrow& (L^1 ,\sigma(L^1,L^\infty)) \\
   &f &\longrightarrow & f
\end{array}$$
Is a continuous injection

Answer (score 0):

This is an immediate consequence of Banach Alaoglu Theroem and the fact that $L^{\infty}$ is the dual of $L^{1}$.